# Angular 4 calendar Material

Tags: angular, calendar

I want to add new angular material calendar.When our mouse pointer in calendar date, it should be highlighted .is there any materials to achieve this task.

Comment: Try this one https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 3):

The built-in datepicker control of Material library comes with an internal Calendar component.

`<mat-calendar><mat-calendar>`

Read more about the calendar here:

https://onthecode.co.uk/angular-material-calendar-component/

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this. These components seems to be the best:
https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar
and https://angular-material-calendar.bradb.net/#
Cheers!